# COMException while adding paths to a ShellLibrary

Tags: c#, windows-api-code-pack

I'm using Windows 7's [Shell Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to overwrite an existing library and add new paths to it, using the managed wrapper available through the [Windows API Code Pack 1.1](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack).

Every now and then, I can't seem to reproduce this in any way, a `COMException` is thrown while adding the paths to the library:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070497): Unable to remove the file to be replaced. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070497)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.IShellLibrary.Commit()
   at ... (local code from here on out)
```

The code is quite straightforward. The error is thrown on the `Add` method.

```
using ( var activityContext = new ShellLibrary( LibraryName, true ) )
{
    Array.ForEach( dataPaths, p => activityContext.Add( p.LocalPath ) );
}
```

**Is there a certain scenario where this exception is to be expected which I can reproduce/test for?**

Assuming this is a bug in the shell libraries, I could just catch the exception and retry doing the operation a couple of times, although I'm hoping for a cleaner 'solution'.

Comment: I would assume based on the exception you are running into some sort of permission problem.  It very well based on 5 minutes of research be a bug in the API itself, I would catch and log the exception, but do nothing about it if it rarely happens.